# Android SQLite column int to float possible?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app out on the Android market that user data is stored in SQLite. I created a database table with a column of ints. I would like to store floats there now. How can I do this? When I try to insert a float, my app seems to throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SQlite [doesn't implement](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) full support for `ALTER TABLE` (only renaming a table and adding a column), you'll have to:

- create a temporary table with the new column format, i.e. float
- copy over the data from the original table into the temporary table (the ints will be "widened" into floats, no data loss here), e.g. `INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM orig`
- drop the original table
- rename temporary table to original table

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit new to SQLite, if I create the new table with, say, the first 5 columns the same names as my original, can I create this new table with unspecified data types? What is an example to create without specifying a data type? Will `INSERT` be able to copy the values with the new table having a different data type?

Comment: The new table is nothing special and has to be created like any other table, i.e. full column definitions including data type. If you keep all column names the same and only have "widening" conversions (e.g. int -> float), you should be able to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` syntax seen in my answer to easily copy all data.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [SQLite does not support the use of `alter table` to change the datatype of a column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).  So, the only solution that I know of is to create a new table (with the particular column not specified as an `int` datatype), fill in the new table, drop the old table, and then rename the new table (via the `alter table` command) to the same name as the old table.